# Search and Highlight Text With Bracketed Text in javascript by regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing one project for tat i want to search and highlight text the words i can able to search the words and multiple words through regular expression.my code is

```
var RE = new RegExp(word_array[i],"gi")
```

word_array nothing but my words are in array format to be search and highlight for ex if

```
         word_array[0] ="tobacco"
         word_array[1] ="chipper(tobacco)"
         word_array[2]="tobacco(snuf)"

var RE=new RegExp("tobacco","gi")
```

the word tobacco in my word_array,this word searched and highlighted in my html pages.but the word like "chipper(tobacco)"in my array having text with bracketed text wont search and highlight i.e `var RE =new RegExp("chipper(tobacco)","gi")`

i tried something with `[abc],(/\[([^\]]+)\],(?:abc)` but not search and highlight 
thank but i tried ur escaping sequence(chipper(tobacco) it search highlight "chippertobacco" only without parentheses i want to highlight the word "chipper(tobacco)" with  parentheses this should be in word_array[i] in loop  so plz tel me how can give code for word_array[i] in var RE = new RegExp(word_array[i],"gi") gi-nothing but global search and case insensitive

thank in advance

plz any one help as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brackets have specail meaning in regex. if you want to match a literal bracket you need to escape it. to match "chipper(tobacco)" use `RegExp("chipper\(tobacco\)","gi")`

Comment: @herotwist: please note that to programmers, these characters `()` are commonly called [*parentheses*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Parentheses_.28_.29), not simply brackets, which usually mean these characters `[]`.

Comment: Quite true. I was simply using the same language as the OP to avoid confusion. I'm pretty sure his native language isn't English.

Comment: thank but i tried ur escaping sequence(chipper(tobacco) it search highlight "chippertobacco" only without parentheses i want to highlight the word "chipper(tobacco)" with parentheses this should be in word_array[i] in loop so plz tel me how can give code for word_array[i] in var RE = new RegExp(word_array[i],"gi")

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Escaping sequence with  Reg Exp

```
                 "chipper\\"(tobacco\\)
```

it wil search and highligt the

"chipper(tobacco)"  and for array

```
          word_array[i].replacereplace("(","\(").replace(")","\\)")
```